# Regex Or and Greedy

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I am trying to perform this regex but I am not sure how to write the or condition because of the greedy behavior of regex.

```
some_text=(?<value>.*)&|some_text=(?<value>.*)$
```

The above regex is exactly what I want but I would like to write a better one that would look like the following:

```
some_text=(?<value>.*)(?:&|$)
```

But because of greediness, this one is not stopping the value when it encounters the first `&` instead it goes back to the end of the string.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just this negation regex:

```
some_text=(?<value>[^&]*)
```

`[^&]*` will match 0 or more of any character that is not `&`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this does not work when I try it. And as far as I understand it, it would match the value to contain a & if it exists. I want to match a value that do NOT contain the &, but the regex should work only if there is either a & OR the end of the string after the value. 

Here is an example that should match: `https://test.com/#/gg/plop?ign=vava&some_text=74381hui1h881&iuri=84`

This should return 74381hui1h881 as the value.

Comment: No `&` need not be there in input string at all. See this regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/nY7qW1/7

Comment: Thanks it worked, I must have not entered the correct input when I tried it. I mark you response as the answer but would you mind explaining me. I think this is using lookahead but I am not sure. Thanks

Comment: No actually it is not a lookahead. As I wrote `[^&]*` will match 0 or more of any character that is not `&`. So if `&` is not present it will match till end of input.